# Meteor app "breaks" when deployed (wrong login parameters, gets stuck in requests)

Tags: meteor

I have created my first meteor app today and am kind of stuck. Everything works extremely well on localhost:3000, very responsive etc. It is a simple task app, where users can post tasks to a feed that displays all tasks an then claim those tasks, removing them from the general feed and putting them into their personal feed. But when I deploy it to a meteor.com server, everything breaks.
This is the js file
https://github.com/valentin-zambelli/brokenjs/blob/master/mvp.js

Accounts.ui.config({
    passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"
  });

gets ignored and whenever I try to post a new task the page reloads, getting stuck on app.meteor.com/?text=some+new+task and doesnt display the task in the general taskfeed. 
I have removed the insecure and autopublish package. Is there anything I am missing here? It kind of seems as if it uses an older, broken build. I also get the ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require when deploying, but I can't really figure out where this is coming from.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was an insanely stupid mistake on my part: The mongodb was still in an older state and caused a conflict. If you have problems deploying your meteor app try

```
meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com -- delete
```

This will delete all resources on the server, including the database. Then do a simple

```
meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com
```